# JavaScript: using reference to "method" changes behavior

Tags: javascript, function-pointers

JavaScript functional programming question.  Here is a screen-scrape of my `node` REPL session.  Why does my `y(4)` call not push into the `x` array?  Is there a simpler way than the `function` near the bottom to do the same thing?

```
> var x = []
undefined
> var y = x.push
undefined
> x.push(3)
1
> y(4)
2
> x
[ 3 ]
> y.call(4)
undefined
> x
[ 3 ]
> (function(data){x.push(data);})(4)  # too much typing :-)
undefined
> x
[ 3, 4 ]
```

Please forgive if this is a duplicate question; it's not clear to me how to search for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter to `.call` is the `this` context to be used inside the function. I believe it will work if you use this instead:

```
y.call(x, 4)
```

When you don't set `this` properly, you are not acting on `x`. When you create a reference `y` to `x.push`, that reference is not bound to `x`. If you want a bound version of `push`, you can use `var y = x.push.bind(x)` as suggested by @go-oleg (or `Array.prototype.push.bind(x)`). Then `y(4)` will push to `x`.

---

Now, the problem with `Array.prototype.push` is that it relies on `this`, being more suited for an object-oriented programming style. A more functional approach, I believe, would be something like the following (illustrated with the underscore library):

```
function push(arr) {
   return arr.push.apply(arr, _.rest(arguments));
}

var x = [];
var pushToX = _.partial(push, x);

pushToX('foo', 'bar');
console.log(x); // ['foo', 'bar']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hUJjz/

Comment: or you can do `var y = x.push.bind(x)` and then just `y(4)`

Comment: @go-oleg Yes, I'll add that.

Comment: `var y = x.push.bind(x)` is what I want.  (Or `var y = partial(x.push.call, x)`, if I can find an implementation of `partial` that I like.)

Comment: @wberry I don't think it's going to work with `partial(x.push.call, x)`, as that would create a partial application of `call` unrelated to `push` (it's similar to your original problem). Go with bind.

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting it.  These are not bound methods or unbound methods, they are just functions accessed via prototype.  Yes?

Comment: @wberry Exactly, they're just functions. Their `this` value is determined dynamically when they're called, and depend on how they're called (as a method or not), unless it's a bound function created with `bind`, or if you force a value on call time using `call` or `apply`.

Comment: @wberry Take a look at my update, I added what I believe to be a more functional approach (although I'm no expert on that matter).